# String object vs. string literal in OutputStreamWriter in Java

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection

I'm making requests to a HTTP server sending JSON string. I used Gson for serializing and deserializing JSON objects. Today I observed this pretty weird behavior that I don't understand.

I have:

```
String jsonAsString = gson.toJson(jsonAsObject).replace("\"", "\\\"");
System.out.println(jsonAsString);
```

That outputs exactly this:

```
{\"content\":\"Literal\",\"pos\":{\"left\":20,\"top\":20}}
```

Now I'm using `OutputStreamWriter` obtained from `HttpURLConnection` to make HTTP, PUT request with JSON payload. The foregoing request works fine:

```
os.write("{\"content\":\"Literal\",\"pos\":{\"left\":20,\"top\":20}}");
```

However, when I say:

```
os.write(jsonAsString);
```

...the request doesn't work (this server doesn't return any errors but I can see that when writing JSON as string object it doesn't do what it should). Is there a difference when using string literal over string object. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the snippet:

```
public static void EditWidget(SurfaceWidget sw, String widgetId) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonWidget = gson.toJson(sw).replace("\"", "\\\"");

        System.out.println(jsonWidget);

        try {
            HttpURLConnection hurl = getConnectionObject("PUT", "http://fltspc.itu.dk/widget/5162b1a0f835c1585e00009e/");
            hurl.connect();
            OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(hurl.getOutputStream());
            //os.write("{\"content\":\"Literal\",\"pos\":{\"left\":20,\"top\":20}}");
            os.write(jsonWidget);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            System.out.println(hurl.getResponseCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.replace("\"", "\\\"")` instruction. It's unnecessary.

You're forced to add slashes before double quotes when you send a JSON String *literal* because in a Java String *literal*, double quotes must be escaped (otherwise, they would mark the end of the String instead of being a double quote inside the String).

But the actual String, in the bytecode, doesn't contain these backslashes. They're only used in the source code.