# How to add backslashes to Json response in Java?

Tags: java, json, string, escaping, backslash

I want to used this but the string that I am getting from a server it comes in the Json regular form. I meant without the \

```
  JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

  System.out.println("=======decode=======");

  String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
  Object obj=parser.parse(s);
  JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
  System.out.println("======the 2nd element of array======");
  System.out.println(array.get(1));
  System.out.println();

  JSONObject obj2=(JSONObject)array.get(1);
  System.out.println("======field \"1\"==========");
  System.out.println(obj2.get("1"));    


  s="{}";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);

  s="[5,]";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);

  s="[5,,2]";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String object vs. string literal in OutputStreamWriter in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882331/string-object-vs-string-literal-in-outputstreamwriter-in-java). You don't want to send backslashes. Your first literal string in your example doesn't contain any backslash.

Comment: the response look like this: {'type':'ongoing', 'trip':trip.pk}

Comment: Have you read my response in the question I linked to? You need backslashes to escape double-quotes in a **Java source code String literal**. But the **actual String** you have doesn't contain backslashes. It is actually `[0,{"1":{"2":{"3":{"4":[5,{"6":7}]}}}}]`. If it contained backslashes, it wouldn't be valid JSON. Add `System.out.println(s)` and you'll see the actual content of the String.

Comment: Do you mean the backslashes are not included in the JSON object? Please edit your question and add the expected and actual output you are getting.

Comment: @JB Nizet, of course it is not valid Json what I need, I need to use it as a string.. what I m getting from the server is something like [0,{"1":{"2":{"3":{"4":[5,{"6":7}]}}}}]  I need to used it in my javaclass like  String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";  <<< as in the code upstairs.. clear?

Comment: No. Not clear. What's the problem? If you're receiving a String `response` from the server, containing `[0,{"1":{"2":{"3":{"4":[5,{"6":7}]}}}}]`, that's exactly equivalent to having `String response = "[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]"`. The backslashes in this String **literal** are only there to escape the double quotes in the source code, in order for the Java compiler not to confuse them with the end of the string literal.

Answer (score 2):

In order to send slashes in Java, you need to escape them.

So assuming you wanted to receive `{\"key\": \"value"\}`, you would need to escape each one of the slashes, in addition to escaping the quotes: `String s = "{\\\"key\\\": \\\"value\\\"}";` The first two slashes in the groups of three are to escape and produce a slash. The next slash is to escape the quote, which is needed because of how Java encloses Strings in quotes.

Now, that's how to do it, but I think it's worth considering if you really do need to do it? Any JSON parser should be able to handle un-slashified responses.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in code, I am getting a response every five seconds... It needs to be fast and good Todd :)

Comment: GOT it working.. a simple String replace would do the trick.. thanks Mike and Todd.. for trying to help